# How can a macro detect if it's at a paragraph beginning?

Tags: macros

**Edit (Nov. 2022):** I've hit a snag with the answer I accepted below. The `\ifvmode` command returns true when I'm *not* starting a new paragraph after a `{verse}` environment. I was asked to make this a new question, which I've done. It can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664853/).

I would like to write a macro that behaves differently at the start of a paragraph. How can I do this?

(Ultimately I would like this macro to take an argument, but am assuming that's not relevant to the MWE.)

Non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo{%
  \ifAtParagraphBeginning% How to do this?
    Hello
  \else
    (hello)
}
\begin{document}

\foo{} % This should print "Hello"
says the quick brown fox jumping over the lazy dog.

The lazy dog says bark \foo{} % This should print "(hello)"
to the brown fox.
\end{document}
```

Edit: Here's a new example, where I hit a problem. I can't get the "@ifnextchar A" to work when it's in the else clause of the \if (is @ifnextchar looking at "\fi" instead of the character that follows?):

```
\newcommand*\foo[1]{%
  \ifvmode
  \else
    \@ifnextchar A%
      {\textsuperscript{#1}\kern -0.15em}%
      {\textsuperscript{#1}\kern 0pt}%
  \fi}
```

Comment: Someone should mention \everypar.  It isn't what you want, but it could be useful.

Comment: Regarding your edit: the way the code is structured, the `\@ifnextchar` test will _always_ yield false because it will not see the next character (that you expect it to see), but the `\fi` (as you concluded yourself in another edit). To make that work you need to take the `\fi` out of the way: `\newcommand*\foo[1]{%
  \ifvmode
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  \testAchar}` where `\testAchar` contains the actual test you want to do.

Comment: OK, maybe I got it. I really have \testAchar{#1}, and it seems to work if I group it: {\testAchar{#1}}.

Comment: @dedded Yes, here TeX expects a single macro argument, which is either a single token (like `\testAchar` or `\fi` or `a`) or a `{-}`-balanced list of tokens, like `{\testAchar{#1}}`. P.S.: In comments use the @<name> feature to reply to comments so people receive a notification.

Comment: Accepting @campa 's answer, since it answers the original question. But I don't understand @phelype-oleinik 's comment as much as I thought I did. Why doesn't this work?: `\newcommand*\foo[1]{%
  \ifvmode%
    \expandafter\@gobble%
  \fi%
  {\testAchar{#1}}}` The `\@firstofone` seems to be needed even with no `\fi` in the way.

Comment: @dedded The case for vertical mode is clear, `\ifvmode` is true and `\@gobble` consumes the `{\testAchar{#1}}`. When you're not in vertical mode, then all is left is `{\testAchar{#1}}`, and then the `\testAchar` macro will look at the next token, which is a `}` and will expand to false (or throw an error, depending on how it's defined). The `\@firstofone` is there to grab the `{\testAchar{#1}}` and leave `\testAchar{#1}`: it removes a layer of braces. That's why you need it.

Comment: This would have been better as a new question.  The "edit: here's a new problem" format makes this very hard to figure out what's been solved and what hasn't.

Comment: @Teepeemm, sounds good: I can convert this to a new question tonight (or this weekend).

Comment: @Teepeemm, new question filed and linked above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the start of a paragraph TeX is in vertical mode, so you can use the `\ifvmode` primitive. Be careful about trailing spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{%
  \ifvmode
    Hello #1%
  \else
    (hello #1)%
  \fi  
}

\begin{document}
\foo{baz} says the quick brown fox jumping over the lazy dog.

The lazy dog says bark \foo{baz} to the brown fox.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is so close (and works for the example I gave). I tried it in my application, however, and hit a snag. I'll update the question with a second example.