# Test for beginning-of-paragraph that works after a {verse} environment

Tags: macros, paragraphs, verse

I've been using a command to automatically place a number specially (on the baseline) if at the beginning of a new paragraph, and normally (as a superscript) otherwise.  See `\fooauto` in the listing below.  It uses `ifvmode` to test for the start of a paragraph.  The code was aided by the Q&A here: [how-can-a-macro-detect-if-its-at-a-paragraph-beginning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510542/).

Unfortunately, `ifvmode` isn't an adequate test for the case where text follows a `{verse}` environment.  The `ifvmode` test returns true in that case whether or not the text starts a new paragraph.

How can I make the start-of-paragraph test better such that it handles this case?

(Note that the modifications to the `{verse}` environment are not necessary to show this problem, but illustrate the no-gap look used by Oxford Press that I'm trying to imitate.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% Copied from article.cls: \topsep and \partopsep added:
\renewenvironment{verse}
               {\let\\\@centercr
                \list{}{\itemsep      \z@
                        \topsep       \z@% new
                        \partopsep    0.5\baselineskip% new
                        \itemindent   -1.5em%
                        \listparindent\itemindent
                        \rightmargin  \leftmargin
                        \advance\leftmargin 1.5em}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}

\newcommand*\footxt[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}} % used if not at start of paragraph
\newcommand*\foopar[1]{#1\enspace} % used if atstart of paragraph
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86143/
\newcommand*\fooauto[1]{%
  \ifvmode% Current test for beginning of paragraph, fails after {verse} env
    \foopar{#1}%
    \expandafter\@gobble%
  \else%
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi%
  {\footxt{#1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\fooauto{1}The fooauto{} command works correctly here at the
beginning of a new paragraph.
\fooauto{2}The fooauto{} command works correctly here when not at the
beginning of a new paragraph.
\begin{verse}
    Start of verse\\
    End of verse.
\end{verse}

\fooauto{3}Start of new paragraph, ifvmode test works correctly.
\begin{verse}
    Start of verse\\
    End of verse.
\end{verse}
\fooauto{4}Not the start of a new paragraph, ifvmode test in fooauto{} failed.
(But Latex somehow knew not to indent, so it knows that we're not
at the beginning of a paragraph.)
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update using supplied MWE

This uses the same logic as below, but just modifies your `fooauto` macro:

```
\newif\ifusefoopar
\newcommand*\fooauto[1]{%
  \if@endpe
    \usefooparfalse
  \else
    \usefoopartrue
  \fi
  \ifvmode
  \else
    \usefooparfalse
  \fi
  \ifusefoopar
    \foopar{#1}%
    \expandafter\@gobble%
  \else%
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi%
  {\footxt{#1}}}
```

---

### Old answer

Although not explicit, it looks a bit like you are trying to typeset a section of the Bible as some Bibles print verses in this way.

I plan to include this kind of feature into my [`scripture`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scripture) package, but haven't done so yet.

However, it may be possible to sufficiently hack it in now depending on the complexity of your requirements.

In the following solution, I have not attempted to make the beginning of paragraphs *within* poetry sections. I'm also not 100% sure of the `@endpe` test, but it seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scripture}
\scripturesetup{
  poetry/indent=0pt
}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g__dedded_at_para_start_bool
\xpretocmd { \__scripture_verse_output:n }
  {
    \legacy_if:nTF { @endpe }
      { \bool_gset_false:N \g__dedded_at_para_start_bool }
      { \bool_gset_true:N \g__dedded_at_para_start_bool }
    \mode_if_vertical:F
      { \bool_gset_false:N \g__dedded_at_para_start_bool }
  }
  { }
  { }
\AddToHook { scripture/verse/before }
  {
    \bool_if:NF \l__scripture_active_inner_bool
      {
        \bool_if:NT \g__dedded_at_para_start_bool
          {
            \cs_set:Nn \__scripture_verse_format:n { \textbf{ #1 } \enspace }
          }
      }
    \bool_gset_false:N \g__dedded_at_para_start_bool
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{scripture}
  \vs{1}This is the start of a paragraph. \vs{2}This is not the start of a
  paragraph. \vs{3}This is not the start of a paragraph.
  \begin{poetry}
    Start of verse
    End of verse.
  \end{poetry}

  \vs{4}This is the start of a paragraph. \vs{5}This is not the start of a
  paragraph. \vs{6}This is not the start of a paragraph.
  \begin{poetry}
    Start of verse
    End of verse.
  \end{poetry}
  \vs{7}This is not the start of a paragraph. \vs{8}This is not the start of a
  paragraph. \vs{9}This is not the start of a paragraph.

  This is the start of a paragraph. \vs{10}This is not the start of a
  paragraph. \vs{11}This is not the start of a paragraph.
\end{scripture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't look like I can take the whole package. Is this `@endpe` part of your package, or built into Latex?

Comment: @dedded `@endpe` is in the `LaTeX` kernel. You could use a similar test in your own macro probably `\if@endpe ...\else ... \fi` Let me see if I can have a go for you.

Comment: @dedded, how's that?

Comment: This works in the MWE and in a non-trivial real case.  Thanks. (Clearly I don't know how to make the @-thing work for people who display Firstname Lastname.)